# Breaking drop-down content out of its parent

Tags: jquery

If you take a look at the jsfiddle below, it has 3 drop-down menus (DROP1, DROP2, DROP3). The content of the first sticks to the left edge, however the second and third ones begin just below their respective button buttons.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/73/

The question is: How to make the second and third drop-downs' contents stick to the left edge as well (without applying a different style to it with a negative margin).

Many thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('.menu ul').slideUp(0);

    jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function () {
        var target = jQuery(this).children('a');
        if(target.hasClass('menu-expanded')){
            target.removeClass('menu-expanded');
        }else{
            jQuery('.menu-item > a').removeClass('menu-expanded');
            target.addClass('menu-expanded');
        }
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
                    .slideToggle(400)
                    .end()
                    .siblings('li')
                    .find('ul')
                    .slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**New Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6a3eZ/74/)

By adding `position: absolute` and `left: 0` to the submenu, it sticks to the left side.

```
ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    ...
}
```

This happens, because it's relative to the next parent container having a `fixed`, `relative` or `absolute` positioning. And that's the `#menu`.

The problem is, the submenu is taken out of the normal flow and the three menu items at the bottoms are getting overlapped.

Comment: Yep, tried that already. Not what I'm looking for; the drop-downs must not overlap the lower menu items :(